# Grouping to add a new column produces one less row than dataset. How do I make the rows match?

Tags: r, grouping, rows

I have a dataframe (df) with 3 columns - a stage number, time data, and pressure data. Here is a portion of it:

```
structure(list(
Stage = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), 
Pressure = c(3.24, 12.218, 9.634, 9.027, 9.027, 0, 14.28, 1.737), 
DateTime = structure(c(1624720853, 1624720854, 1624720855, 1624720856, 1624720857, 1624905025, 1624905026, 1624905027), 
tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")),
class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

I want to calculate the slope/derivative (change in pressure over change in time) for pressure point for each stage. I have figured out how to calculate the slope, but there are sometimes large gaps in stages and I don't need slope for changes in pressure between stages.

I have code that I believe would work, but because it is looking at the difference in rows, the output will always going to be one less row than than the total number rows within a stage.

```
df<- df%>% 
  group_by(Stage) %>%
  mutate(dp.dt = diff(Pressure)/as.numeric(diff(DateTime)) )
```

This is the error, and like I mentioned, I believe it is happening because the code is looking at the difference in rows, which should result in one less row than the true number of rows in a stage:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `dp.dt`.
i `dp.dt = diff(Pressure)/as.numeric(diff(DateTime))`.
i `dp.dt` must be size 5 or 1, not 4.
The error occurred in group 1: JobStage = 1.
```

In the end, I am looking for something like the table below. Is there a way to induce an NA, add a row, or fill the missing row with something so that I get my desired table?

Please let me know if I need to clarify anything.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

| Stage | Pressure | DateTime | dp.dt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3.24 | 2021-06-26 10:20:53 | 8.978 |
| 1 | 12.128 | 2021-06-26 10:20:54 | -2.584 |
| 1 | 9.634 | 2021-06-26 10:20:55 | -0.607 |
| 1 | 9.027 | 2021-06-26 10:20:56 | 0.000 |
| 1 | 9.027 | 2021-06-26 10:20:57 | NA |
| 2 | 0 | 2021-06-28 13:30:25 | 14.280 |
| 2 | 14.28 | 2021-06-28 13:30:26 | -12.543 |
| 2 | 1.737 | 2021-06-28 13:30:27 | NA |

Answer (score 3):

The `diff` returns output with length one less than the original data length.  Just append `NA` to the `diff` and it should work

```
library(dplyr)
df%>% 
  group_by(Stage) %>%
   mutate(dp.dt = c(diff(Pressure), 
    NA_real_)/as.numeric(c(diff(DateTime), NA_real_)) ) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 × 6
  Stage Pressure DateTime            class      row.names   dp.dt
  <dbl>    <dbl> <dttm>              <chr>          <int>   <dbl>
1     1     3.24 2021-06-26 10:20:53 data.frame        NA   8.98 
2     1    12.2  2021-06-26 10:20:54 data.frame        -8  -2.58 
3     1     9.63 2021-06-26 10:20:55 data.frame        NA  -0.607
4     1     9.03 2021-06-26 10:20:56 data.frame        -8   0    
5     1     9.03 2021-06-26 10:20:57 data.frame        NA  NA    
6     2     0    2021-06-28 13:30:25 data.frame        -8  14.3  
7     2    14.3  2021-06-28 13:30:26 data.frame        NA -12.5  
8     2     1.74 2021-06-28 13:30:27 data.frame        -8  NA
```

Comment: I tried this on my full dataset, and an error appears. It says "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed". Suggestions?

Comment: @new2data It is just that `NA` used should be `NA_real_`  Updated the post

Answer (score 1):

You may use `lead`/`lag` to get next and previous value respectively.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(DateTime = ymd_hms(DateTime)) %>% 
  group_by(Stage) %>%
  mutate(dp.dt = (lead(Pressure) - Pressure)/as.numeric((lead(DateTime) - DateTime))) %>%
  ungroup

#  Stage Pressure DateTime              dp.dt
#  <dbl>    <dbl> <dttm>                <dbl>
#1     1     3.24 2021-06-26 23:20:53   8.98 
#2     1    12.2  2021-06-26 23:20:54  -2.58 
#3     1     9.63 2021-06-26 23:20:55  -0.607
#4     1     9.03 2021-06-26 23:20:56   0    
#5     1     9.03 2021-06-26 23:20:57  NA    
#6     2     0    2021-06-29 02:30:25  14.3  
#7     2    14.3  2021-06-29 02:30:26 -12.5  
#8     2     1.74 2021-06-29 02:30:27  NA
```